# How to echo category_description() without stripping out html tags?

Tags: theme-development

I'm in archive.php and attempting to write out the current category's description with full html. However, category_description() prints without the html markup.

How can I force it to retrieve the full description complete with the html tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

echo get_term_field( 'description', get_query_var( 'cat' ), 'category', 'raw' );
```

Comment: thats gr8 and i even +1'ed it but it creates a php error: "PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string"